# How to load movie on top of three.js canvas

Tags: canvas, three.js, html5-video

I need to have short semi transparent movies to appear from time to time on top of a three.js canvas - similar effect to THREE.GlitchShaderPass but with a video.

Should I render a plane in front of the camera that plays the videos?

Or make a new canvas on top of three.js one?

Is there a more lightweight/efficient way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try

http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.videotexture/examples/videotexture.html

and adjust the transparency of the material ;)